# rolling back a view to a previous version of the same view

Tags: sql-server, deployment, fluent-migrator

I'm using FM to deploy a database. As a part of that deploy, I'm rolling out a view. The changes go like this:

R1: create view

R2: no change to view

R3: add a column to the view

R4: no change

R5: remove the column from the view

The view is created by a script that is in source control. Let's say that I deploy R3 and then decide that I should roll back to R2 (I'm thinking of a production site that I don't want to leave in an odd state). So the view's script (drop/create) is in a local file. I can't use that script again because the local version is at R3 but I want it to go back to R1 (or R2).

**How can I roll the view back to the previous version reliably using FluentMigrator**? The only option I can think of is keeping the view create script in a string in my Migration class. But it seems like I'd need to have every version of it in a string in my class --  very unwieldy and a hard sell to the team.

Every realistic solution to this that I can think of sort of goes against the idea of source control -- having a single version of a thing locally and keeping track of its changes over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this feature into FluentMigrator -- ability to execute a script straight from source. You can get it here:

https://github.com/jcollum/fluentmigrator

Currently only supports SVN. Hasn't been integrated into the main branch yet.

Answer (score 0):

One very simple way is to do something like:

```
if (object_id('dbo.myView', 'V')) is not null
   drop view [dbo].[myView]
go
create view [dbo].[myView] as

select foo, bar
from dbo.Orders
```

Now, if you need to need to alter that view, you make your changes to this script and deploy them.  It'll drop the view if it exists and create it fresh.  From a source control standpoint, all you're doing is making changes to a text file so you should be able to store it efficiently, look at the differences pretty simply, etc.  In other words, you can do all the things that source control does really well because it's just text.

Comment: Nope, that won't work. Think about what's going on with the file versioning and source control.

Comment: It's weird that you say that it won't work.  I suggested this because I've used it and it works for me.  Good luck finding whatever it is that you're looking for.

Comment: OK I'll explain: you have a view in a script that is a drop/create for R5 of the view. You run that script. Now you want to rollback to the previous version of the same view (e.g. R3). Well the script that you have locally is R5. So how do you use the version of the script you have locally to get to R3 of that view? You can't. You'd have to get it out of source control.

Comment: That is what source control is for; going back in time for a particular object and looking at the revision history.  But let's pretend that you don't have source control.  I've also accomplished what you're looking to do by renaming the existing view and creating the view anew each time.  So, you could have multiple versions of the same view, only one of which your code accesses.  If/when you need to roll back, you drop the "live" version and rename the appropriate version to the live name.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But have you gotten this to work within FluentMigrator?